# Iframe apps integration to my fanpage

Tags: facebook, iframe

I'm having some problem with my custom welcome page integrating to my fanpage. I uploaded the custom html/css and images in a server on hostgator on the root directory. The main domain under the server is the site which fanpage I'm creatiing. But in my fanpage under the welcome tab it shows my entire site rather than my custom welcome page. what is the problem here? can you define me the canvas URL and page tab URL please? 
I'm having severe problem in the issue. need your help badly.

Answer (score 0):

Your page URL tab is pointing to your website or maybe you have something like:

```
root
|
|-- index.html // related to the website and not the facebook page
|-- fb_index.html // should be loaded when called on Facebook
|-- other css, image and html files
```

And you are using the default domain as URL: `domain.com` which will load domain.com/index.html

I prefer creating a folder (or two in the below case) under your root:

```
root
|
|-- index.html // related to the website and not the facebook page
|-- other css, image and html files
|-- fb // all Facebook related files tab and Canvas if needed in the future
    |
    |-- tab
        |
        |-- index.html // this should be loaded inside Facebook
        |-- other css, images, js related to the Facebook tab
```

Now you can set your URL in the App settings to: `domain.com/fb/tab/`

Comment: Thanks a lot. My canvas url is: http://paleo30daychallenge.com/fb/tab/ and tab url: is http://paleo30daychallenge.com/fb/tab/index.html

Comment: it's giving me 404...are you actually creating these folders and putting your content there?

Comment: Yap. I created the folder and uploaded my .html .css and images there.

Comment: nop..not working...soo How can i fix this? do you have any suggestions?

Comment: It seems that you didn't upload the files to that folder!

Comment: hmm...But I uploaded them correctly...Should I upload it under the public_html? I didn't create any folder here. I uploaded all under the same folder like: root directory/fb/tab/my files(index.html, contact.php, images,). Is it ok?

Comment: Of course! you need to create the `fb` and it's child `tab` folders inside the `public_html` folder (this is the default for most web-hosts and **NOT** the root folder!) and then put your files there.